# How to read google sheet to model c#

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I'm using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4. I have the follow c# model:

```
class NameIdModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}
```

According to tutorials I wrote the next code to read sheet data to my model:

```
var result = new List<NameIdModel>();
        var range = "NameId!A2:B";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                _service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(Settings._spreadSheetId, range);
        ValueRange response = request.Execute();
        var values = response.Values;
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var row in values)
            {
                int id;
                if(!Int32.TryParse(row[1].ToString(), out id))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                result.Add(new NameIdModel {
                    Name = (string)row[0],
                    Id = id
                });
            }
        }
        return result;
```

It works fine, but I need to read data from sheet without reading by index to property (something like ORM).

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more detail on what exactly do you need?

Comment: Some method, that can map sheet data according to headers to c# class.